Validation Rule on File
I was asked to ensure that files cannot be deleted after 24 hours. I tried to create a validation rule, but the closest object I found to 'File' in the Object Manager is the 'ContentVersion' object. However, when I run a query from the Developer Console, this object has a series of fields that I cannot use for the validation rule. In other words, I don't understand 1) which object I should create the validation rule on, since I can't find one called 'files'; 2) if it is ContentVersion, how can I use all the fields I see in the Developer Console through the validation rule? Additionally, I need the rule to execute only for a specific record type of account, not for all files in the org, for which I also couldn't find a field. Does anyone have more clarity on this issue? I apologize for the inconvenience again, and thank you in advance.


The SObject you're looking for is probably ContentDocument (looking through IdeaExchange, it appears that ContentVersions can't be deleted, but entire ContentDocuments can)
Validation rules don't get run on deletions

You need to have a before delete trigger and use .addError() on record instances from trigger.old or trigger.oldMap. This may be possible with a flow too, but I'm not as well versed in flows.
You'll either need to use dot-notation in a query in that trigger to be able to access data from the Parent field, or go through the ContentDocumentLink SObject to get at the Account recordtype (if it is related to an Account at all). For that, you'd need to read through Understanding relationship fields and polymorphic relationships (since ContentDocumentLink can point to more than just one type of SObject).

Record-Triggered Flows do not currently support ContentDocument, ContentDocumentLink, or ContentVersion (I checked just to make sure). Triggers are definitely the right solution.
